# swagger: how to validate formData

Tags: validation, swagger, flasgger

So far I'm able to do swagger validation if the parameters are from **"in": "body"** or if the input expected is in a **json format**.
However, I can't find how to validate a simple **string** entered as **formData**.

Below is my swagger script (in json format)

```
v1swag = {
    "cancels_post": {
        "tags": ["/api/v1"],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "token",
                "in": "formData",
                "type": "string",
                "required": True,
                "description": "Cancels the provided token.",
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success!",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the **schema** as it seems to only work for **"in": "body"**

I've been searching the net but can't seem to find the light.
Though I will still be searching... Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different source media type has to be consumed here. Specify "consumes" member to include media type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
v1swag = {
    "cancels_post": {
        "tags": ["/api/v1"],
        "consumes": [
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
         ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "token",
                "in": "formData",
                "type": "string",
                "required": True,
                "description": "Cancels the provided token.",
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success!",
            }
        }
    }
}
```